# Apple sharing icon the way to go?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns

Clearly the Apple share icon is coming a vert popular web standard for sharing. Do you think it can become an conventional usage? Should we adopt it and promote it more?

[image: Apple Share Icon]

Comment: You know what those chaps are like - check out the legal side first!

Comment: This isn't really a suitable question to be asking here. As per the [FAQ] *If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.* Also, you don't cite any evidence stating that the sharing icon *is* very popular anyway, so it's really just your own opinion. If you have evidence that it *is* so popular, and also have a specific usage in mind for it then you could restructure the question around that, but if you're just starting a discussion on it then this site isn't the place to have this.

Comment: @JonW The question is legit, The formulation might not, still that icon **is** trending: I saw templates, e-commerce sites, — some even pretty mainstream, IIRC — sporting it. (I will try taking note of the url each time that happens, from now on, so I'll be able to document its popularity) I actually hate it, I find it confusing, and I logged in on UX searching some ammo to justify my istinctive rejection of it. And all I find is... denial of the problem. Disappointing.

Comment: @ZJR As per my comment above, there was very little detail provided in the question to explicitly answer it. If you have a particular question about this icon that we can answer (that's not a discussion topic) then feel free to ask that here, or visit Chat to talk to people about it, but this question - although of interest - isn't a good fit for a Q&A site.